# How to create a org.openqa.selenium.Cookie with the isSecure flag to false

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When creating a cookie and defining that I want the isSecure field to be false:

```
 driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue(), cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getPath(), cookie.getExpiry(), false));
```

it is Selenium, actually WebDriver sets the parameter to true:

```
driver.manage().getCookies().forEach(cookie -> {
     System.out.println("Adding cookie isSecure: " + cookie.isSecure());
}); //prints Added cookie isSecure: true
```

I use selenium version:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't know why this happens.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: AFAIK, if you set a cookie without specifying the secure flag, this always defaults to false. What happens if you do not explicitly try to set it false?

Comment: @demouser123 unfortunately, the webdriver cookie has no setters

Comment: @Rahul L I changed to FirefoxDriver and field of cookie secure is correct. Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work in the Firefox . Looks like issue is only with chromedriver/chrome.

As a work around use Firefox.

**Explanation:**

Java Binding code for adding the cookies.

```
public Cookie(String name, String value, String domain, String path, Date expiry,
      boolean isSecure, boolean isHttpOnly)


driver.manage().addCookie(
                    new Cookie("test", "test", "google.com", "/", null, false,false));
```

For above code Webdriver is sending proper values to chromedriver server.

```
[1566377805.242][INFO]: [70c91dc21b299384c804d153e40a6b0d] COMMAND AddCookie {
   "cookie": {
      "domain": "google.com",
      "httpOnly": false,
      "name": "test",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": false,
      "value": "test"
   }
}
```

Even Chrome Devtools is calling Network.setCookie with proper data

```
DevTools WebSocket Command: Network.setCookie (id=26) BB77CD380D314C209C8F2F8AE97C504D {
   "domain": ".google.com",
   "httpOnly": false,
   "name": "test",
   "path": "/",
   "secure": false,
   "url": "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl",
   "value": "test"
}
```

For get call its returning "secure": true.

```
[1566377805.253][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Response: Network.getCookies (id=30) BB77CD380D314C209C8F2F8AE97C504D {
"cookies": [ {
{
      "domain": ".google.com",
      "expires": -1,
      "httpOnly": false,
      "name": "test",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": true,
      "session": true,
      "size": 8,
      "value": "test"
   }]
```

**From above logs:** It looks like its issue with chromedriver/chrome and not the Selenium Webdriver JAVA binding.

**For Firefox its working properly**

WebDriver sends the post request

```
DEBUG   -> POST /session/8600dbc1-e2cd-449d-ad0d-fc5261e37266/cookie {
  "cookie": {
    "domain": "google.com",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "test",
    "path": "\u002f",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "test"
  }
}
```

Marionette  also sending proper data

```
Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,3,"WebDriver:AddCookie",{"cookie":{"domain":"google.com","httpOnly":false,"name":"test","path":"/","secure":false,"value":"test"}}]
```

Receiving correct value "secure":false

```
Marionette  DEBUG   0 -> [0,4,"WebDriver:GetCookies",{}]
1566378528552   Marionette  DEBUG   0 <- [1,4,null,[{"name":"test","value":"test","path":"/","domain":".google.com","secure":false,"httpOnly":false}]]
```

Not an issue in Firefox/Geckodriver